# Can we simulate "default arguments" for generic parameters?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I built a small type-level library to simplify writing pairs of functions of the form

```js
function a(...): T | undefined;
function b(...): T;
```

where b is derived from a by throwing an exception if undefined is returned. The basic idea is as follows:

```js
export enum FailMode { CanFail, CanNotFail }
export const canFail = FailMode.CanFail;
export const canNotFail = FailMode.CanNotFail

export type Failure<F extends FailMode> = F extends FailMode.CanFail ? undefined : never;
export type Maybe<T, F extends FailMode> = T | Failure<F>;

export function failure<F extends FailMode>(mode: F): Failure<F> {
  if (mode === canFail) return undefined as Failure<F>;
  throw new Error("failure");
}
```

Now we can combine `a` and `b` into a single function that takes one extra parameter to distinguish the types:

```js
function upperCaseIfYouCan<F extends FailMode>(x: string | undefined, mode: F): Maybe<string, F> {
  if (x === undefined)
    return failure<F>(mode);
  return x.toUpperCase();
}

// both of these now work
let y: string = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo", canNotFail);          // can throw, but will never return undefined
let z: string | undefined = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo", canFail); // cannot throw, but can return undefined
```

Now in most cases I want the `canNotFail` variant, and I'm wondering if there is a way to make this the "default" in that I don't have to pass the `canNotFail` parameter in that case, so that the following would work:

```js
let y: string = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo");  // can throw
```

I already determined that this cannot be achieved via default arguments, because the type of the default argument must be unifiable with `F`. Is there a way to achieve this in a different way, such that defining functions like `upperCaseIfYouCan` is similarly easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler isn't happy about you specifying a default parameter because someone can always come along and manually specify the generic type parameter when calling, like this: `upperCaseIfYouCan<FailMode.CanFail>("");`.  If you don't expect that to happen you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress that error, and additionally, you should give the `F` type parameter its own [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that without an obvious choice for `F` the compiler will choose your default instead of the complete `FailMode`:

```
function upperCaseIfYouCan<F extends FailMode = FailMode.CanNotFail>(
    x: string | undefined,
    mode: F = canNotFail as F
): Maybe<string, F> {
    if (x === undefined)
        return failure<F>(mode);
    return x.toUpperCase();
}
```

This should work with your use cases:

```
let str = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo", canNotFail); // string
let strOrUndef = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo", canFail); // string | undefined

// this is the behavior you want
str = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo"); // string
```

---

On the other hand, you could just use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to handle the two different ways of calling your function.  While generics are more elegant conceptually, overloads might be more intuitive in this situation:

```
function upperCaseIfYouCan(x: string | undefined, mode: FailMode.CanFail): string | undefined;
function upperCaseIfYouCan(x: string | undefined, mode?: FailMode.CanNotFail): string;
function upperCaseIfYouCan(
    x: string | undefined,
    mode: FailMode = FailMode.CanNotFail
) {
    if (x === undefined) return failure(mode);
    return x.toUpperCase();
}

let str = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo", canNotFail); // string
let strOrUndef = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo", canFail); // string | undefined

str = upperCaseIfYouCan("foo"); // string
```

It's not any safer inside the implementation than the version with the type assertion, but at least the overload can't easily be called the wrong way (there's no `F` to manually specify).

---

Okay, hope one of those gives you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAsAKCTpBSEAHjAPYBOALkcAK5hIBiIAlgDYCyZAJsukgDCIYCw4AaISIByZKmPZIAvvkIly1JPDLAoNeCIVIAvMzZdeEAHTDR5gNyqC6yvp16tMuUdMLufGy95cxwnIlJXJCoATxhkBToKCAAeJnCqCGAeKDMOfwgAPhNmdMzs3IsA2yMAfiQ6LIgAM1ZgCB4kAC4kNoA3CApHXDUIzRi4pE4QaIAjFIAVSTSSDKycv0si03mkAB8KxJSmAqGwl00mhvgqVh0kJvND1NK1ivyCgAowS26mAEpfo8kqkilhhoRCKwmkgvpYTMZTAY7Bw-kgklREsB6o0Wm0OiB1kCjicwhCqAALChkADuPQgtIAohQqRQPgAiB4cQ5sv5DCEqbBhS7Aa63LF0GBxCjCKAQACSTQAmmQ6LZnisyoS8nDfOZ8oFgLJghxPqTCMRunoKK0AOZ7bF8XHtcRmgjfPi-YpIo1GAnMMIAybTObJK22pag11IKEw4jw0wNR2tdp-KMQ9GY+5EkGwvi8qMZihY4hWKhkACqkoGMogH3z4OUoQb7AgNCtxQlUprCuVqpE7KaZDIbMk3u85l5SAA9FOkGHgDawi221QKAB5CjlnEdqvSgnypUq2wDocjzzI9iTmdz1e2+2J5rJnhNiHthO77uHvvAE-Dq+z+dF0FbABRwUBIFgBBkEVDAzlGGhMgYN44QEapzEkWwfXMRsG3ONxdH0QxsN1bUqiIjg+RGDR8I8MdjUUEjKmsTDxw4F8qMicZ4mzZZiFWcoNj4LYSg1V5BOY8jFDqB8nQ6bo+gGU5cPg+4rhuO5OXYJ5eP4rUmM+d0IF+QMEmBY5YIbCEY1zZAEURSTUULcUcSfJA-VM4lKIhAgKSpWk2kZZlKAHIkeS8nChTUsV6g-fceyPfsLRva0F3vFy8UkQzAVIiSL0DQC0qTPFwuFUU7k7as4q-Y8koK-YZKfTLLBqbKmINLCUUtW8FxKqLyti2V4u-D4o1q7q7Xq9LnSjLLkL4YpxPa1j2ADCzvMhaEPjjOyHUfPFHNbTNNMOGz63WggnKQEsy0rLt9zrcLQObVtkp3O7Buq-sOVPUcggUf9kttJcXqtDct0dN7Ko+3tj2+4dfry+xpwA8bCr29p2IIN8Yveg8Ya+wc-yR69AKbJQgA)